# Search for all G+ posts mentioning or linking to a domain or url?

Tags: google-plus

Is there any way to search or structure a url in Google+ to get all posts that link to or reference a URL or domain? Similar to the way you can do it in Pinterest like http://pinterest.com/source/domain.com

This structured query does not get nearly everything: https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/domain.com

Answer (score 4):

Google+ does not offer a specific API for getting posts that reference a specific URL or host. As Joanna mentions, you can use the [`activites.search`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/search) method to do a full text search based on any given string, which could be a URL.

Comment: Hi! Obsolete links all around or am I wrong? Anyway interesting answer, thank you.

Comment: Fixed one link. Looks like Ripples [1] are now obsolete so removed that section.

[1]: https://plus.google.com/+googleplus/posts/dbVpERPaqYA

Answer (score 3):

Google+ does not offer a URL that you can use to search to target specific shares. However, you can use the Google+ API to make an [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) API call, where you can specify a `query`, which does a full text search.  The API will return the *public* posts that contain the matched text.